# Is there a way to allow all users to scp from a specific machine to another specific machine without password?

Tags: ssh, scp

Currently I have a machine setup to send files it generates via a script to a remote server for file storage, where each user has their own folder on the remote server, which they can then SFTP into to get their files.

Currently, when the machine generating the files copies them over, via SCP, it prompts for a password for the user it's sending to.

What I would like to be able to do is enable the machine to send the files to the individual user accounts without prompting for a password. I've read a few ways to do this by creating ssh keys in each user's accounts. However, due to the volume of users, I was wondering if there was a way to enable machine1 to be able to scp files to any user account on the remote file server without prompting for a password each time?

Comment: I'm a little confused when you say "enable the machine to send the files to the individual user accounts...". This seems like it could be resolved by properly set permissions if it is always userA scp-ing data from hostA to hostB:/home/user*, or some other restricted destination location. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the script is using scp <user>@server:, so when it runs, we use <script command> <user> which tars up a load of image files, and then sends them to <user> on the remote server via scp. But there are quite a few <user> accounts, so I was wondering if there was a way to blanket authentication from one machine to another without placing keys in each users' account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up [host-based authentication](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Host-based_Authentication) on the target host to accept connections from the source host. This will work for any kind of SSH access, not just SCP. If you want to limit users to just SCP, there are ways to do that. see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/641275/make-linux-server-allow-rsync-scp-sftp-but-not-a-terminal-login) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

sshpass -p  scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no source dest

I have used it on some linux machine. Don't know if it always work (last day i tried on osX and it refused cause it will break ssh security)

BTW you have to install sshpass